# in case of rotation of object there are some "artifacts"

Tags: javascript, 3d, webgl

everybody. There is a textured 3d object. [image]
In case of its rotation there are distortions. [image]
To what it can be connected?

P.S. if to disconnect shadowing of object, will change nothing

Comment: Shader code would be helpful

Comment: Since it's a sphere you can simply offset texture coordinates to simulate rotation.

Comment: Is it possible you draw the object twice?

Answer (score 0):

Mistake it was very amusing:
The draw function is responsible for copying () which lies in setInterval

```
    this.draw=function(FPS){setInterval(function(){for(var i in self.element){self.element[i].draw();};/*self.drawShadow();*/},1000/FPS);};
```

And so, I simply forgot to give FSP.
That is - there was draw () and became: draw(60)